# Like button shows more likes than Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Facebook LIKE button shows larger amount of likes, than API!!!

I have a link: `http://premija.intensa.pro/person/130/ilona_kvelde`

When I create Like button on my page, it shows 48 likes at this moment (You can try to enter link in Get Code page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

But, when I execute `FQL` query, it shows less.

You can try in `FQL` Explorer

```
SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count 
FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://premija.intensa.pro/person/130/ilona_kvelde'
```

Answer (score 0):

From [running this in the explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count%20%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://premija.intensa.pro/person/130/ilona_kvelde%27):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "share_count": 2, 
      "like_count": 30, 
      "comment_count": 0, 
      "total_count": 32
    }
  ]
}
```

You're right, there's a difference. There's probably some sort of time-delay, or privacy stuff, not sure. Notice that there's also a difference for [running 'http://www.google.com'](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count%20%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27). But nevertheless if this is an important difference for you then you should file a bug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs). Seems to be on a macro-level and thus by design, but its worth a shot.